# не могу понять, как работает метод read_hotkey() в библиотеке keyboard

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-keyboard

В доках написано, что он просто возвращает название нажатых клавиш, но ничего про то, что он где-то сохраняет результат прошлого вызова.
Когда я вызываю метод второй и последующие разы, при нажатии клавиши/клавиш он возвращает и названия из прошлого вызова

Вот функция, декоратор и вызов:

```
def hotkey(widget, section, option):
    key = keyboard.read_hotkey()
    widget.value = key.upper()
    widget.update()
    print(key)
    if key in keys:
        config.set(section, option, keys[key])
    with open(path, "w") as config_file:
        config.write(config_file)
```

```
def htk_decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args):
            key = ""
            page.dialog = dlg
            dlg.open = True
            page.update()
            config.hotkey(*args)
            key = "uu"
            dlg_tx.value = key
            dlg.update()
            dlg.open = False
            page.update()
            dlg_tx.value = ""
        return wrapper

    hotkey = htk_decorator(config.hotkey)
    
    tabs.htk_skillslot1.on_click = lambda _: hotkey(tabs.tx_skillslot1, "HOTKEYS", "SkillSlot1")
```

Получается вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каждый раз я жму по одной клавише.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался, необходимо было выставить значение False в аргумент "suppress"

```
def hotkey(widget, section, option):
    key = keyboard.read_hotkey(suppress = False)
    widget.value = key.upper()
    widget.update()
    print(key)
```